# node system and procedural in blender

Tags: modeling, node-editor, add-on, procedural

What node system add-ons,other than sverchok, animation nodes and every thing nodes are there in Blender. And, if available, procedural add-ons (not in a node interface) for modeling, animation, etc?

Comment: Sverchok and animation nodes are basically all, at the moment. Take a look at Houdini, it's incredible for node based procedural workflows

Answer (score 1):

There was many attempts, blendgraph from Atom for example, but if you want to make real node tool you should do much of work. Motion tools was also node-based.
procedural geometry in addons without nodes is tissue from Alessandro Zomparelli (he participate also in sverchok and his tissue addon partially is adaptive polygons node, there is also adaptive edges node from Linus Yng and much the same from zeffii).
Procedural is also citymaker, prokitectura and many-many other in all of kind.

Answer (score 1):

There's also a relatively new node system now called "*Sorcar*" (formerly known as *ProcGenMod*).

The development thread is over at Blenderartists https://blenderartists.org/t/sorcar-formerly-procgenmod-procedural-modeling-in-blender-using-node-editor/1156769/284 , i've seen cool use-cases. The add-on developer has taken much feedback into consideration and it's also b28 ready.